# My PHP get YouTube video api function isn't printing anything

Tags: php, api, youtube

Just been crating an API (as an exercise) to get my latest YouTube video and nothing is being printed. I'm very new to PHP and have just started to create myself a website

youtube_api.inc.php

```
    <?php

function get_latestvideo($username)
{
    if (true || (time() - filetime("{$GLOBALS['path']}/cache/video_cache.txt")) > 3600)
    {
        $videos = array();

        $data = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{$username}/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2&alt=json";
        foreach (json_decode(file_get_contents("$data"))->feed->entry as $video)
        {
            $url = (array)$video->link[0];

            $videos[] = array(
                'title' => $video->title->{'$t'},
                'desc' => $video->{'media$group'}->{'media$description'}->{'$t'},
                'url' => $url['href'],
            );
        }

        file_put_contents("{$GLOBALS['path']}/cache/video_cache.txt", serialize($videos));
    }else{
        $videos = unserialize(file_get_contents("{$GLOBALS['path']}/cache/video_cache.txt"));
    }
}

function get_playlists($username)
{

}

?>
```

init.inc.php

```
    <?php

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("youtube_api.inc.php");

?>
```

videos.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

include('init.inc.php');

print_r(get_latestvideo('thegigglesquid'));

?>
```

This last file is supposed to print the `$videos` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never return anything from your function.

Try adding:

```
return $videos;
```

At the end of your function, outside of the `if() {} else {}` statement.

```
function get_latestvideo($username) {    
    $videos = array();
    if (true || (time() - filetime("{$GLOBALS['path']}/cache/video_cache.txt")) > 3600) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
    return $videos; // <-- Important!
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that sorted it. Thanks, you're a massive help for such an inconspicuous and small soloution :D